# Configure SIP Trunk from Lync 2013 to Cisco Call Manager v6

Tags: cisco, sip, lync, voice, unified-communications

I'm implementing Enterprise Voice for Lync, and I have to get Lync to work with a antiquated Cisco Call Manager version 6. The SIP trunk has been created but I get this error on my Lync servers:

A PBX gateway has been marked as down.

Gateway name: 192.168.1.14.
Cause: A gateway failed to respond to a request within allotted time or was unable to route the request due to some error.
Resolution:
Verify that the gateway is up and can respond to calls.

192.168.1.14 is the IP address of the call manager. I can ping the call manager. Port configuration on both Lync and Call manager look correct (TCP 5060). Performing telnet from Lync FE to 192.168.1.14:5060 is successful.

I have no idea what could be wrong. The version of call manager is so old that I can't find any information on making it work with Lync 2013.

So I'm hoping that someone on these forums has done something similar and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of this hotfix:
KB2640253

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/650006ae-3199-4dfe-b31e-a7c6a948224d/lync-unable-to-call-out-through-dialogic-gateway-link-to-siemens-hipath-pbx?forum=ocsvoice

Comment: Thanks Yasser. In the end, the guys in charge of the call manager concluded that it was too old to work with Lync 2013. They've since upgraded it and its working now. Also the timeout value on Lync 2013 is set too short. Increasing the timeout value also helped solve the timeout issue.